# Photon transport in coupled waveguides

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

I am currently doing an undergrad research project on quantum photonics studying the transmission/reflection properties on photons in waveguides. However, I am struggling to understand how the Hamiltonian for the coupled system comes about, for example with ring resonators or emitters. How is the Hamiltonian derived?

Also, is there any text out there which has a description of the interaction Hamiltonians of simple coupled waveguide systems?